# What layer is formed on Titanium when soaked in Hydrogen Peroxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

A few pieces of TI-6AL -4V ELI ASTM F136 Titanium jewelry were left to soak in a small cup of 3% household Hydrogen Peroxide.

After about a week of soaking, all of the Titanium had acquired a smooth, dark grey/black coating. In the process, the Hydrogen Peroxide acquired a yellow tint.

I am familiar with Ti color anodizing, but this is a color that, as far as I know, is impossible to obtain with traditional anodizing methods. It more closely resembles industrial anodizing and the grey/silver color they obtain.

What process is taking place?

What is the grey coating made of?

Is it just oxidized titanium?

[image: Grey Ti Jewelry]

Comment: the yellow color is from peroxotitanic acid and the grey color is titanium dioxide

Comment: @SafdarFaisal Thank You! That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I have some papers that show the reactions.. If you want i'll write an answer at some point